GIMP: semi-transparent edges after cutting despite disabled "Feather edges"
I have the problem that when I select an area and press Ctrl+X or Del it creates these feathered/semi-transparent edges.
This happens even when I have "Feather edges" disabled as you can see from the screenshot.
And anything I could find about this issue just recommended to disable this, which obviously isn't working.
All I want is that the image gets cut exactly at the selection border without changing the surrounding pixels on both sides of the border. So how can achieve this.



Welp. Apparently the problem was antialiasing.
As you can see on the screenshot antialiasing is disabled.
But apparently if you disabled that after the selection has been made, it still applies antialiasing to the cut after it is disabled.
So one has to disable antialiasing and then redo the whole selection for it to not antialias.
Guess I learned something new today :D

Actually, what you want is to obtain partially opaque pixels, so that if you put this over another color the partially opaque pixels blend with the new background and recreate a smooth edge. So in practice you don't cut but use Color erase paint mode or the Color to alpha filter/ See here for a more detailed explanation.
